# I need software to reset my PC to computer defaults when I press a certain group of keys

Tags: windows, windows-10

I want to be able to reset my computer to defaults and delete everything by pressing a certain group of keys at the same time (Ctrl Alt Win Shift Del)

Comment: A little sidebar - most keyboards will not take more than 3 inputs at a time. What keyboards are you using?

Comment: You have already asked [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1362320/i-want-to-make-a-auto-hotkey-script-that-resets-my-pc-to-factory-defaults). Please don't ask the same question twice.

Answer (score 1):

This is REALLY REALLY broad. You need to break your question into several smaller pieces.

Start by finding a method to "reset my computer to defaults and delete everything". You'll have to define what "defaults" and "everything" are. Then you'll need a way to get it done, scripts, or hard drive wiping, some kind of network image deployment.

There are lots of applications out there that can execute actions when key combinations are pressed. Autohotkey for example: https://autohotkey.com/

In truth, you're probably looking for a way to make your computer 'clean' when someone comes snooping and the answers you're going to get here are not going to be what you want. Proper hard drive wiping (unrecoverable) takes time, a long long time and doesn't really work with SSDs. Image deployment takes time too and doesn't wipe stuff.

Comment: If a question is “really broad” it should be modified so that isn’t the case before you submit your answer